# jQuery set <input type="range"> value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

**Update: This was a bug which has been fixed by now (Chrome 18).**

---

I have a `<input type="range">` and I'm trying to set its value by jQuery. That basically doesn't do anything.

Then, I tried hiding/showing as I thought it would be a drawing problem, but to no avail did I so.

Lastly, I hid the `<input>` and showed it using `show(1)`, which would mean a fading-in of 1ms. This *did* set the value, however after doing so the `<input>` isn't draggable anymore.

I made this fiddle up: http://jsfiddle.net/MhDf7/2/.

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on here? I'm using Chrome 10.

Comment: Reproduced.  That looks like a Chrome or Webkit bug.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks. Would you recommend reporting it to Chrome or perhaps to jQuery?

Comment: It's not a jQuery bug; it also happens when setting `[0].value`.  Yes.

Comment: UPDATE: They are all fixed now. Tested in Chrome 20.

Comment: @Derek: Indeed, thanks. It also works in Chrome 18 so I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a browser bug. The exact same thing happens when using [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HxT64/)) or when using vanilla JavaScript ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsD6w/)).

However, even if the display isn't updated, the form still submits the correct value.

You might want to fill a bug report... On your jsFiddle page, do the following:

1. Click the Page menu .
2. Select Report a bug or broken website.
3. Choose an issue type from the drop-down menu. The web address of the webpage you're on is recorded automatically.
4. If possible, add key details in the 'Description' field, including steps to reproduce the issue you're experiencing.
5. Keep 'Send source of current page' and 'Send screenshot of current page' checkboxes selected.
6. Click the Send report button to report a Google Chrome bug.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work on Chromium 18 and the problem is still there. Seems like Chrome and Chromium version updates are not the same.

Comment: What about version 20? It's stable now.